# differential system-bounded solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We consider the differential system $$Y'=AY,\quad \mbox{in} [0,+\infty[, Y(0)=Y_0$$
where $A$ is $n \times n$  matrix diagonalisable, $Y_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $Y \in \mathbb{R}$
What's the suffisant and necessary condition of $A$ such as:

1) the problem admits an bounded solution in $[0,+\infty[$

2) the problem admits a solution $Y(t)$ such as $||Y(t)||-->+\infty$ when $t-->+\infty$.

For the question 1), the solution of the problem is $Y(t)=Y_0 e^{At}$ for all $t\in [0,+\infty[$. but i have difficulties to continued the answer.

Thank's for the help.

Comment: Do you mean $Y\in \mathbb R^{n\times 1}$?

Comment: Non! $Y\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** start with the case in which $A$ is diagonal.

details:

in this case, one solution goes to $\infty$ iff there is a diagonal value $\lambda$ with $\Re \lambda>0$ (if this is the value $a_{ii}$ then the solution with initial value $e_i$ is $\exp (\lambda t)e_i$).

For the general case: write the diagonalization and express the initial value in terms of the eigenvectors. The conclusion is that
there is a solution such as $|Y(t)|\to\infty $ iff there is an eigenvalue $\lambda$ with $\Re \lambda>0$.

---

Let us write $$
A = P^{-1}DP
$$
with $P$ diagonal.
$$
Y(t) = \exp (At) Y(0) = P^{-1}\exp (Dt)PY(0)
\\
\iff PY(t) = \exp (Dt) PY(0)
$$
Now if you write
$$
Y(0) = P^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^n y_k e_k,\\
PY(t) = \exp (Dt) \sum_{k=0}^n y_k e_k = \sum_{k=0}^n
 \exp(\lambda_k t)y_k e_k.
$$

Comment: I kow that $e^{At}=\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{A^i}{i!}$ but my problem is that i don't know how we express the solution with eignevetors. Can you help in this point please

Comment: OK. Take a look at the second part.

Comment: Why you write $Y(0)=P^{-1} \sum_{k=0}^n y_k e_k$ who are $y_k$ and $e_k$? and why $e^{Dt}=e^{\lambda_k t}$? I don't understand

Comment: here $e_k$ is the kth vector of the canonical basis of $R^n$, $y_k$ is the coordinate of $PY(0)$ on this basis.

Comment: as $D$ is diagonal, so is $\exp Dt$ and when the kth coefficient of the diagonal is $\lambda_k$ then $\exp (Dt) e_k = \exp(\lambda_k t) e_k$

Comment: Okay, i understand how we can write that $$PY(t)=\sum_{k=0}^ne^{\lambda_kt}y_ke_k$$ with $\lambda_k$ the eigenvalues of $D$. How we find the necessary and suffisants conditions to assure that $Y(t)$ is bounded for all $t\in [0,+\infty[$? How about $P$?

Comment: Can you help me please

Comment: just write any function in this form and use the triangle inequality.

Comment: Sorry but hwo is $\lambda_k$?